# Apache NetBeans (mac) crashes after installing plugin

Tags: netbeans

I've got this issue with my Apache NetBeans 15 in my Mac. After installing a plugin (dark mode interface) the app didn't run anymore... The app main window (and everything else) is flat grey and nothing works anymore.

I uninstalled it a few times with appCleaner and reinstalled it with the same result. I can't find the plugin file to erase it from my OS...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Go to finder and press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> then put this path:

```
/Users/(how you are called as user)/Library/Application Support/
```

This is in my case:

```
/Users/damino/Library/Application Support/
```

In this folder you should see a folder "NetBeans", you can delete this folder or open it an find in modules the theme that you have been installed and delete them.

In my case I installed Dracula theme and my IDE got crashed, I deleted all file that have something common with Dracula theme form modules